# Two questions about material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have two questions about material-ui.

Does JSS has built-in css hint? For example, display: "flex"

currently I could not get any hint about what can be the value of "display".

Is there a way to achieve this?

Another question is, is there a way to pass a variable into the style?

For example, I have a style in JSS style, such as - aa: {width: 5 * x}

is there a way to pass the variables into the style or is there any alternative ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

solves 2nd part of your question

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/5y2oqnmw6l)